# Can't return Graphics object from a function in Win32 C++ GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, gdi+

I am creating some functions that facilitate a little bit GDI+. I have created this function to begin paint to be used in WM_PAINT:

```
Graphics StartPaint(HWND win, HDC *hdc, PAINTSTRUCT *ps)
{
    *hdc = BeginPaint(win, ps);
    Graphics g(*hdc);
    return g;
}
```

It gives compile error and takes me to "gdiplusgraphics.h" and points to 
this line:

```
Graphics(const Graphics&);
```

saying that it is private.

After several tries I discovered that the problem is with the return statement in the function. Why does the return statement give such an error, and how can I solve this problem?

I use codeblocks.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact error? The line that the error is pointing to seems to be the copy constructor for ```Graphics``` object.

Comment: You cannot copy-construct a `Graphics` object. That should be evident. What's dubious is what you hope `StartPaint` to solve.

Comment: Also please describe what you are trying to do... It seems *odd* to say the least.

Comment: There is a `Graphics(HDC)` constructor. Strange that it is finding `Graphics(const Graphics&)`

Comment: I just try to save few line in WM_Paint:
Instead of writing three lines to make graphics object ready to use, I am trying to create a single function that does do this job. What baffled me most is that if I remove the return statement, I got no compile error, but the function becomes useless.

Comment: @wally the error is on the return statement when it's trying to copy the graphics object outside the function.

Comment: No bafflement is due. C++ doesn't try particularly hard to enforce even those rule violations it can see.

Comment: @ IInspectable Why cannot I copy Graphics object?

Comment: A GDI+ `Graphics` object wraps a [device context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts). For obvious reasons, the Windows API doesn't provide calls like `DuplicateDC` or `CopyDC`. Since those API calls wouldn't make sense it's easy to see why you cannot copy-assign or copy-construct a `Graphics` object.

Comment: @llnspectable This does make a sense, thank you.

Comment: As such, you will have to create the `Graphics` object dynamically and return a pointer to it, eg: `Graphics* StartPaint(...) { ... return new Graphics(*hdc); }` ... `Graphics *g = StartPaint(...); ... delete g;` Which would be better handled using `std::unique_ptr`: `std::unique_ptr<Graphics> StartPaint(...) { ... return std::make_unique<Graphics>(*hdc); }` ... `auto g = StartPaint(...); ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau This works well, thank you very much.

Comment: @VinoRue You can post an answer and mark it so that other community members can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. The function now works well as follows:

```
Graphics *StartPaint(HWND win, HDC *hdc, 

PAINTSTRUCT *ps)
{
    *hdc = BeginPaint(win, ps);
    return new Graphics(*hdc);
}
```